# Civi CRM Expert in Europe wanted

Tags: civimember, profile, custom-templates, invoice

i (Austrian based company) am looking for a CIVI-CRM-Expert in Europe (preferred) for helping with various implementations on a basic level  (customizing invoices, create profiles for a kind of portfolio of members...)

Please send your references and rates to gerald.koellersberger@k-con.net

I am looking to hear from you!

Gerald

Answer (score 5):

Please refer to this link https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors to get/contact a CiviCRM expert in your area